# Does the stack get reset when you return from a recursive function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, stack, cx-oracle

I keep getting a stack error midway through my code:

```
WINDOWS-1252' codec failed (RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object)
```

My problem is, I iteratively run my recursive function. As in, I keep passing it a new value. The actual function doesn't do more than 8 passes on any given value. Why does the stack overflow? Is there anyway to clear it since any data it collected is unnecessary when the new value is passed? Or am I just misunderstanding recursion?

Edit: Here's the code

```
#iterative function     
for row in ids:
 cursor.execute('SELECT PRIMARY_EQUIP_FED_FROM, ISPANEL FROM PANELBOARDS 
 WHERE PANE_ID = :panel', {'panel': row[0]})
 prime = cursor.fetchone()
 panelRecursion(prime, prime[1], row[0])
 columnTracker = 1
 rowTracker += 1
 wb.save('demo.xlsx')

#Recursive Function
def panelRecursion(primary, isPanelFlag, initial):
 global columnTracker
 if primary is None:
    return
 if isPanelFlag == 0 and initial == 0:
    cursor.execute('SELECT NAME FROM ELECTRICAL_EQUIPMENTS WHERE ELEQ_ID = :panel', {'panel': primary[0]})
    eName = cursor.fetchone()
    if eName is None:
        return
    if "LCR" in eName[0]:
        sheet.cell(row=rowTracker, column=columnTracker).value = eName[0]
        columnTracker += 1
        return


 if isPanelFlag or initial > 0:
    panel = {'panel': primary[0]}
    p2 = primary[0]
    if initial > 0:
        panel = {'panel': initial}
        p2 = initial
        initial = 0
    cursor.execute('SELECT PRIMARY_EQUIP_FED_FROM, ISPANEL FROM PANELBOARDS WHERE PANE_ID = :panel', panel)
    primary = cursor.fetchone()
    panelRecursion(primary, primary[1], 0)
    columnTracker += 1
    cursor.execute('SELECT NAME FROM PANELBOARDS WHERE PANE_ID = :panel', {'panel': p2})
    eName = cursor.fetchone()
    if eName is None:
        return
    sheet.cell(row=rowTracker, column=columnTracker).value = eName[0]
    return False

 else:
    panel = {'panel': primary[0]}
    p2 = primary[0]
    cursor.execute(
        'SELECT PRIMARY_EQUIP_FED_FROM, PRIMARY_ISPANEL FROM ELECTRICAL_EQUIPMENTS WHERE ELEQ_ID = :panel', panel)
    primary = cursor.fetchone()
    panelRecursion(primary, primary[1], 0)
    columnTracker += 1
    cursor.execute('SELECT NAME FROM ELECTRICAL_EQUIPMENTS WHERE ELEQ_ID = :panel', {'panel': p2})
    eName = cursor.fetchone()
    if eName is None:
        return
    sheet.cell(row=rowTracker, column=columnTracker).value = eName[0]
    return
```

Comment: Please provide your relevant code so we can help.

Comment: I have added my code!

Comment: Double check your indentation.  It matters in Python.  Especially make clear what code is part of the function.

Comment: I cleaned up my identation and marked the iterative and recursive functions. The iterative functions gives new values to the recursive function

Comment: What encoding is the data in the database? What encoding are you using on the client?